# SlickUtil - NoClassDefFoundError when accessing API

Tags: java, rendering, slick2d

When I try to do anything with SlickUtil, I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/newdawn/slick/opengl/renderer/Renderer
    at org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont.<clinit>(TrueTypeFont.java:28)
    at Text.init(Text.java:14)
    at Main.main(Main.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.newdawn.slick.opengl.renderer.Renderer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

Code

```
public static Font font;
public static TrueTypeFont uf;

public static void main (String[] args) {

    font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20);
    uf = new TrueTypeFont(font, true); // Throws the error

}

public static void render (String text) {

    uf.drawString(0, 0, text);

}
```

Why is this error being thrown, and what can I do about it?

Otherwise, is there a method to display 2D text with OpenGL without using SlickUtil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this error being thrown, and what can I do about it?

It is being thrown because the JAR file containing that dependency is not on the *runtime* classpath.  (Apparently, the JAR file was available when your application was compiled.  If it wasn't, then the source code that refered to the class would not have compiled.)

What you need to do is to find / identify the JAR file, and add it to the runtime classpath of your application.

---

> Is there a method to display 2D text with OpenGL without using SlickUtil?

That is a request for us to find or recommend software for you.  It is off-topic.

And moot ... if you sort out the *real* problem with your classpaths.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

`What you need to do is to find / identify the JAR file, and add it to the runtime classpath of your application.`

How can I do this?

Comment: 1) If you compiled the source code, then you already have the JAR file.  2)  It depends on how you are running your application, but the answer is probably ... "read the manual entry for the 'java' command" - specifically the material that talks about the classpath.

Comment: The compiled jar file is already imported, yet it still has the error.

Comment: You have misunderstood my answer.  The problem is with the runtime classpath, not the compile time classpath.  Please read the references I added to my answer.  They should help you understand the (probable) root cause of your problem.

Comment: Thank you! This helped alot